# Symfony2 - change configuration of vendor bundle

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, bundles

I faced a proble: i need to change vendor bundle configuration. How can i do that correctly?

Vendor bundle config:

```
namespace Oro\Bundle\DataGridBundle\Extension\Toolbar;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

use Oro\Bundle\ConfigBundle\Config\ConfigManager;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /** @var int */
    private $defaultPerPage;

    /**
     * @param ConfigManager $cm
     */
    public function __construct(ConfigManager $cm)
    {
        $this->defaultPerPage = $cm->get('oro_data_grid.default_per_page');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $builder = new TreeBuilder();

        $builder->root('toolbarOptions')
            ->children()
                ->booleanNode('hide')->defaultFalse()->end()
                ->booleanNode('addResetAction')->defaultTrue()->end()
                ->booleanNode('addRefreshAction')->defaultTrue()->end()
                ->integerNode('turnOffToolbarRecordsNumber')->defaultValue(0)->end()
                ->arrayNode('pageSize')->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                    ->children()
                        ->booleanNode('hide')->defaultFalse()->end()
                        ->scalarNode('default_per_page')->defaultValue($this->defaultPerPage)->end()
                        ->arrayNode('items')
                            ->defaultValue([10, 25, 50, 100])
                            ->prototype('variable')->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
                ->arrayNode('pagination')
                    ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                    ->children()
                        ->booleanNode('hide')->defaultFalse()->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $builder;
    }
}
```

The question is - how can i change `->arrayNode('items')` to my custom array without editing bundle configuration.php?

Comment: Have a look to: `http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html`

Comment: Why do you need to override this part of the configuration? What are you trying to do? Wouldn't changing the values in your `app/config.yml` work as expected?

Comment: @Touki because these parameters are not present in config.yml. As i understand - this config tree is built 'on the fly'...

Comment: @StepanYudin That still doesn't answer the root of your problem. It's very unlikely you have to change the Configuration **definition** of another bundle. What are you trying to achieve, exactly? That `$items` will be your custom-loaded-from-database/parameters.yml array values? Or do you want to you want to change the prototype of items?

Comment: @Touki, ok, this array simply represents pagination component's 'View per page' values. I just want to add new values 500 and 1000 without changing the bundle's source code

Comment: Then what's wrong with adding these values in your `config.yml`, [like this](http://pastebin.com/N0tXdcYU)?

Comment: I already tried this. 
Here is error: **Uncaught exception** 'Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException' with message 'Unrecognized option "toolbarOptions" under "oro_data_grid"' in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to change the configuration builder, just configure it as you want:

```
bundle_name:
    toolbarOptions:
        pageSize:
            items: [10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000]
```

Comment: please look up at the last comment of topic